# error in the compile compile version

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.andt.projectalpha"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1-alpha1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

There is an error in the line

> ```
> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
> ```

The suggested solution was to keep all the versions same so I did. But there's still an error.

Hovering on the statement says "Found versions 25.3.1, 25.0.0"

Comment: Can you add full build.gradle?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira I have added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change everything in dependencies to  **26.0.0-beta1**

for example

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
```

and

```
compileSdkVersion 25 (to 26)
targetSdkVersion  25 (to 26)
```

Comment: Did that, and now Android Studio can't find repositories. Clicking on **Install Repository and Sync Project** doesn't seem to work.

Comment: can you make completely new project and try if everything works there

Comment: yeah i did that. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: A new project, everything is working fine for me now.

Comment: so cant you put right tick on my answer so everybody knows that it was helful